# Property 'residenza' does not exist on type formGroup<any>

Tags: angular, forms, formgroups

So I was tring to build a form in angular 14 but I get the error that only some of the fields of the form do not exist on type formGroup, particularly these fields are 'note','senioriy','email'and 'domicilio' whereas other fields do not throw errors.
Below is the code of my template html, my type script, my model, and the error I get.
**HTML**

```
<div class="componentWrapper d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div
      class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade show"
      role="alert"
      *ngIf="added == true"
    >
      <h5 style="width: auto;">Candidato aggiunto con successo!</h5>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close"
      ></button>
    </div>
    <div class="titleSpace">
      <h1 class="text-center">Aggiungi Candidato</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="formWidth m-auto formSplit"
      >
      <form
        
        #formCandidato="ngForm"
        id="formDemetra"
        [formGroup]="aggiungiCandidato"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event.submitter.id)"
      >
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna" >
          <label for="name">Nome</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="nome"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.nome.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="candidato.nome"
            formControlName="nome"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid':
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.nome.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.nome.errors">
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Cognome</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="cognome"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.cognome.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="candidato.cognome"
            formControlName="cognome"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid':
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.cognome.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.cognome.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.cognome.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Data di Nascita</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            class="form-control"
            id="dataDiNascita"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.dataDiNascita.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="candidato.dataDiNascita"
            formControlName="dataDiNascita"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && !aggiungiCandidato.dirty }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && !aggiungiCandidato.dirty">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.dataDiNascita.errors
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna" >
          <label for="name">Residenza</label>
          <input
          *ngIf="this.aggiungiCandidato.controls['residenza'].value!= undefined"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="residenza"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.residenza.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.residenza"
            formControlName="residenza"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid':
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.residenza.errors
            }"
          />
          <div
            *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.residenza.errors"
          >
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted &&
                aggiungiCandidato.controls.residenza.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Domicilio</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="domicilio"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.domicilio.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="candidato.domicilio"
            formControlName="domicilio"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid':
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.domicilio.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.domicilio.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted &&
                aggiungiCandidato.controls.domicilio.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Cellulare</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            class="form-control"
            id="cellulare"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="candidato.cellulare"
            formControlName="cellulare"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Email</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
            formControlName="email"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Disponibilita</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
            formControlName="email"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Titoli di Studio</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
            formControlName="email"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Seniority</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="seniority"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.seniority.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.seniority"
            formControlName="seniority"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.seniority.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.seniority.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.seniority.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Note</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="note"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.note.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.note"
            formControlName="email"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.note.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.note.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.note.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Job Position</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
            formControlName="email"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group casella-colonna">
          <label for="name">Colloqui</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            [placeholder]="
              submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
                ? placeHolder
                : placeHolderNull
            "
            required
            [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
            formControlName="email"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors
            }"
          />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors">
            <div
              *ngIf="
                submitted && aggiungiCandidato.controls.email.errors.required
              "
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="float-end mt-3">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="save&Clear">
            Registra e aggiungi altro
          </button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="add">
            Aggiungi Candidato
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobalVariables } from 'src/app/helpers/globalVariables';
import { Candidato } from 'src/app/model/candidato';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { PopupGestioneCommesseComponent } from 'src/app/component/pop-up/popup-gestione-commesse/popup-gestione-commesse.component';
import { Colloquio } from 'src/app/model/Colloquio';
import { CandidatoServiceService } from 'src/app/service/candidato-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidato-aggiungi',
  templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidato-aggiungi.component.css'],
})
export class CandidatoAggiungiComponent implements OnInit {

  
  candidato : Candidato = new Candidato ( 1,"","",new Date(),"","",0,"","",[],"",0,[],"");
  colloqui : Colloquio[] = [];
  globalVariables: GlobalVariables;
  aggiungiCandidato!: FormGroup;
  title = 'formValidation';
  submitted = false;
  added = false;
  placeHolderNull = "";
  placeHolder ="Inserire campo obbligatorio"
  formLoader : boolean = false;

  @ViewChild('formCandidato')
  formCandidato!: NgForm;

  constructor(
    private matDialog: MatDialog,
    public globals: GlobalVariables,
    private candidatoService: CandidatoServiceService,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.globalVariables = globals;
  }

  //Metodo submit per aggiungere uno o più candidati a seconda del bottone cliccato
  onSubmit(event: string) {
      if (event == 'add') {
        this.submitted = true;

        //Se il form non è valido blocca la registrazione
        if (this.aggiungiCandidato.invalid) {
          return;
        }

        this.candidatoService.aggiungiCandidato(this.candidato).subscribe({
          next: (data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.goToList();
          },
          error: (error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
        });
      } else if (event != 'add') {
        this.submitted = true;

        if (this.aggiungiCandidato.invalid) {
          return;
        }
        this.candidatoService.aggiungiCandidato(this.candidato).subscribe({
          next: (data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.saveAndReload();
          },
          error: (error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
        });
      }
    }
  
  
    openListaClientiPopup() {

      const popup = this.matDialog.open(PopupGestioneCommesseComponent, {
        width: '1200px',
        height: '500px',
        enterAnimationDuration: '300ms',
        exitAnimationDuration: '300ms',
        data:{data:this.colloqui}
      });
      popup.afterClosed().subscribe(item=> {if(item!=null){
        this.globalVariables.colloquioId=item;
        this.candidato.colloqui[0].id=item;
      }});
    }

  //Inizio metodi di reindirizzamento
  goToList() {
    this.router.navigate(['/elenco-candidati']);
    
  }

  

  saveAndReload() {
    this.formCandidato?.reset();
    this.router.navigate(['/aggiungi-cliente']);
    this.submitted = false;
    this.added = true;
  }
  //Fine metodi di reindirizzamento

  ngOnInit(): void {

    

    this.added = false;
    this.globalVariables.changeValue(true);

    this.aggiungiCandidato = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: ["", [Validators.required]],
      nome: ["", [Validators.required]],
      cognome: ["", [Validators.required]],
      dataDiNascita: ["", [Validators.required]],
      residenza: ["", [Validators.required]],
      domicilio: ["", [Validators.required]],
      cellulare : ["",[Validators.required]],
      email : ["",[Validators.required]],
      disponibilita : ["",[Validators.required]],
      titoliDiStudio : ["",[Validators.required]],
      seniority : ["",[Validators.required]],
      note : ["",[Validators.required]],
      JobPosition : ["",[Validators.required]],
      colloqui : ["",[Validators.required]],
    });

    this.formLoader = true;
   
  }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
import { Colloquio } from './Colloquio';
import {JobPosition} from './JobPosition';


export class Candidato {

    id : number;
    nome : string;
    cognome : string;
    dataDiNascita : Date;
    residenza : string;
    domicilio : string;
    cellulare : number;
    email : string;
    disponibilita : string;
    titoliDiStudio : string[];
    seniority : string;
    idJobPosition : number;
    colloqui : Colloquio[]
    note? : string;
    
   
 
 
    
    constructor( id: number , nome:string, cognome:string, dataDiNascita:Date,residenza : string,domicilio : string,
        cellulare:number, email:string, disponibilita : string, titoliDiStudio : string[], seniority : string, idJobPosition : number,
        colloqui : Colloquio[] , note? : string) {
 
         this.id = id;
         this.nome=nome;
         this.cognome=cognome;
         this.dataDiNascita=dataDiNascita;
         this.residenza = residenza;
         this.domicilio=domicilio;
         this.cellulare=cellulare;
         this.email = email;
         this.disponibilita = disponibilita;
         this.titoliDiStudio = titoliDiStudio;
         this.seniority = seniority;
         this.note = note;
         this.idJobPosition = idJobPosition;
         this.colloqui = colloqui;
         
 
    }

   
 
 
 }
```

**ERROR**

```
Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:116:44 - error TS2339: Property 'residenza' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.     

116             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.residenza"
                                               ~~~~~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:116:44 - error TS2339: Property 'residenza' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.     

116             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.residenza"
                                               ~~~~~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:185:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

185             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:185:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

185             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:211:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

211             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:211:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

211             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:237:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

237             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:237:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

237             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:263:44 - error TS2339: Property 'seniority' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.     

263             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.seniority"
                                               ~~~~~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:263:44 - error TS2339: Property 'seniority' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.     

263             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.seniority"
                                               ~~~~~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:289:44 - error TS2339: Property 'note' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

289             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.note"
                                               ~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:289:44 - error TS2339: Property 'note' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

289             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.note"
                                               ~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:315:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

315             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:315:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

315             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:341:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

341             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.


Error: component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.html:341:44 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

341             [(ngModel)]="aggiungiCandidato.email"
                                               ~~~~~

  component/area-hr/candidato/candidato-aggiungi/candidato-aggiungi.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: './candidato-aggiungi.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CandidatoAggiungiComponent.




× Failed to compile.
```

I tried looking on the Internet for solutions but without any luck

Comment: Look like for these two errors, you should use `candidato` instead of `aggiungiCandidato`. Anyway, it is not recommended to use `[(ngModel)]` when you are using Reactive Form. To assign value to formControl, you should use `patchValue()` method from `FormControl` or `FormGroup`.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, I copied and pasted the code and didnt pay attention to what I was binding the ngModel to, it took me forever to figure this out. I sincerly appreciate it! Thank you!